# I want this type of Listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want this different shape of container in listview.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below plugin hope this works for you

[Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

```
StaggeredGrid.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
  children: const [
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 0),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 2,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 1),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 2),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 1,
      mainAxisCellCount: 1,
      child: Tile(index: 3),
    ),
    StaggeredGridTile.count(
      crossAxisCellCount: 4,
      mainAxisCellCount: 2,
      child: Tile(index: 4),
    ),
  ],
);
```